# Recursive DOMDocument from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array that looks like following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Residential
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [Type] => Townhouse
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Value
        [value] => 250000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Other
        [value] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Price
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [PriceAmount] => 200000
                [Contract] => No
                [StampDuty] => 20000
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Date
                [value] => 2015-09-16
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Income
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [RentalAmount] => 2000
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Period
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Unit] => Monthly
                    )

            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Contact
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [Type] => Owner
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Company
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Business] => ABC Contacts
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Person
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Title
                                [attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Value] => Mr
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => First
                                [value] => Michael
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Surname
                                [value] => Jordan
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Home
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Phone
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Mobile
                                [value] => 0414888999
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Phone
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Fixed
                                [attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [CountryCode] => 
                                        [AreaCode] => 
                                    )

                                [value] => 99999999
                            )

                    )
            )

    )
)
```

I am using a recursive function to try to generate a DOM in order to get that array in XML:

```
private function GenerateElements($dom, $data)
{
    $child = '';
    if (empty($data['name'])) {

        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $item) {
                $child = $this->GenerateElements($dom, $item);
            }
        }

        return $child;
    }

    // Create the element
    $element_value = (!empty($data['value'])) ? $data['value'] : null;
    $element = $dom->createElement("ns5:" . $data['name'], $element_value);

    // Add attributes
    if (!empty($data['attributes']) && is_array($data['attributes'])) {
        foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute_key => $attribute_value) {
            $element->setAttribute($attribute_key, $attribute_value);
        }
    }

    // Any other items in the data array should be child elements
    foreach ($data as $data_key => $child_data) {
        if (!is_numeric($data_key)) {
            continue;
        }

        $child = $this->GenerateElements($dom, $child_data);
        if ($child) {
            $element->appendChild($child);
        }
    }

    return $element;
}
```

Called via:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$child = $this->GenerateElements($doc, $arr);
if ($child)
     $doc->appendChild($child);
$xml = $doc->saveXML();
```

The issue I'm having is that the code is overwriting each element, and the dom I am finishing with, only contains the very last array [5].

I've tried so many things, but this recursive function is the end product so far - please help me tweak it so it doesn't overwrite the elements and all 5 array parts are included.

Edit: Just FYI I have tried to adapt my code from here
http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/06/29/easily-create-xml-in-php-using-a-data-array/

Surprised his original code doesn't work down further levels.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when it's called via `$doc = new DOMDocument(); $child = $this->GenerateElements($doc, $arr);`, the first time it goes into the loop, it just keeps iterating through without actually appending the `$child` to the `$doc`:

```
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $child = $this->GenerateElements($dom, $item);
        }
```

So it will recurse into each element, but then overwrite the value when it returns back to the root node on the next iteration. So, you're left with the final return value of just the last array item in the root node.

You might play around with appending it there, like in this untested code, and see if it gets you anywhere:

```
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $child = $this->GenerateElements($dom, $item);
            if ($child)
                $dom->appendChild($child);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks yeah i tried that but it actually appends the item to the top of the document,  out of order

Comment: so it's getting late and I can't quite figure this one out. but I've got all the nodes in an xml document, but they're all sitting under the "residential" node as the root node. something goes awry with the first sibling sequential numbered array location. hth, you can see my progress in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/QafCSrq9

Comment: i appreciate you taking the time :)